# java custom view in flutter

Tags: java, flutter, dart, android-custom-view

I have a custom view, written in Java and want to use it in my flutter project. Is it possible to convert it to dart-native code or use it as a java class in flutter?

Custom view is quite complex and I am not very experienced in dart language, so would be great to have it either converted to dart or use it as it is

Comment: Yes you can with method channel

Comment: Rahul Variya, can you elaborate, please?

Comment: i have an example of it. if you interested then I can post bounce of code

Comment: bunch *********

Comment: Rahul Variya, I would appreciate if you share your example

Comment: Okay will post in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Step 1 :*** You have to write method channel into dart code:

```
static Future<void> initSupport({
    String? url,
    String? appId,
    String? clientId,
    String? id,
  }) async {
    await _channel.invokeMethod<void>('initSupport', {
      'url': url,
      'appId': appId,
      'clientId': clientId,
      'id': id,
    });
  }
```

You have to write into your view where you want to open java view to init this method channel
After this, you have to open your project in android studio

***Step 2:*** Check the below code to get method channel from dart

```
class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {

  override fun onNewIntent(intent : Intent){
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    setIntent(intent)
  }

  private val CHANNEL = "channelname"

  override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {

    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
        call, result ->
      if(call.method == "initSupport"){
        initSupport(call)
        result.success(true)
      } 
    }
  }
```

***Step 3:*** method of init is

```
   fun initSupport(call: MethodCall){
       val url = call.argument<String>("url") ?: ""  // here is your dart data
      val appId = call.argument<String>("appId") ?: "" 
      val clientId = call.argument<String>("clientId") ?: ""
      val id = call.argument<String>("id") ?: "1"

     // You can init your view here like below 
   Toast.makeText(this,"hello from native", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() 

     }
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but my custom view is a custom animation, which shows information to UI. Therefore it should be drawn in  dart classes only, without involving any native code(overwise I need to write a separate custom view for iOS part)

Comment: I did it already